# CodeIgniter: json_decode array issues

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

On my client side I'm sending an ajax request with jQuery in the following matter:

```
$.post(script.php, { "var1":"something", "var2":"[1,2,3]" }, function(data) { }, "json");
```

On the server side, in the CodeIgniter's controller I'm receiving the values like so:

```
$var1 = trim($this->input->post('var1'));
$var2 = trim($this->input->post('var2'));
```

My question is how do I convert the string in `$var2` into a PHP array.
I tried using `json_decode($var2, true)` but it returns a `null` since "[1,2,3]" is not a legal JSON string by itself.

Also, if you believe there is a better way for me to read the values on the server-side please show me how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Galen stated in his comment to my question, it works.
The reason I got a `null` from `json_decode` is because it tried it with a non-array value, which requires a double `"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$var2 = trim($this->input->post('var2'), "[]");

$array = explode(",", $var2);
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I prefer not to. Today it's a simple array, tomorrow a more complex structure of array of arrays, etc.